How to store SVN credentials in WSL2 Ubuntu environment?
TL;DR

I'm experiencing inconvenience due to having to authenticate for every SVN operation in the WSL2 Ubuntu environment.
I want to store the authentication information, but I'm not even prompted to save it. Despite various configuration attempts, the issue persists.

Details

Hello, I'm using Windows 11, WSL2, Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, and SVN@1.14.3 (r1914484).

In the WSL2 environment, I have to enter my SVN credentials for every operation, which is quite inconvenient.

For Git, I can easily integrate with Windows credentials using the Git Credential Manager setup, but I haven't found relevant information for SVN.

I sought solutions through ChatGPT, but the issue remains unresolved. I suspect the problem may be due to the lack of tools for credential storage in the Ubuntu image. I've tried the following methods without success:

Installing Gnome Keyring

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev

vim ~/.subversion/servers

# edit
[global]
store-passwords = yes
store-plaintext-passwords = no

vim ~/.subversion/config

# edit
[auth]
password-stores = secret-service,gnome-keyring
store-passwords = yes
store-auth-creds = yes

rm -rf ~/.subversion/auth/


Typically, SVN asks whether to save the credentials after entering account information, but this interaction does not occur.

Does anyone have insights or suggestions on this issue? I would greatly appreciate any leads to solve this problem.

Thank you.



You might try to remove the white space, i.e. store-passwords=yes. I faintly recall having had problems when there was white space around the equal signs. Just a wild guess, hope it helps.
